# How do I replicate this PHP hashing implementation in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, cryptography

I'm attempting to recreate a password hashing implementation in node.js (LTS latest--14.x) that was originally written in PHP (7.2). I believe the node.js implementation that I've written should do the exact same thing; however, the node.js implementation differs after the first pass of the hash in the loop. What am I missing here?

PHP implementation (I cannot change this since it's part of a web framework and existing authentication relies on the hashing mechanism staying the same):

```php
$algo = "sha512";
$salt = "someSalt";
$password = 'somePassword';
$count = 32768;

$hash = hash($algo, $salt . $password, TRUE);
// $hash is the same as in the corresponding line in the node.js implementation
do {
  $hash = hash($algo, $hash . $password, TRUE);
  // $hash differs from the node.js implementation after the first pass here... why?
} while (--$count);
```

Node.js implementation:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

const algorithm = 'sha512';
const salt = 'someSalt';
const password = 'somePassword';
let count = 32768;

let hash = crypto
        .createHash(algorithm)
        .update(salt + password)
        .digest('binary');
// hash is the same as in the PHP implementation here
do {
  hash = crypto.createHash(algorithm).update(hash + password).digest('binary');
  // hash differs between the two implementations after the first pass here... why?
} while (--count);
```

EDIT: Updated to show the original Node.js implementation where I did not stringify data being passed to `update()`.

Comment: Try to check it to `.digest('hex')`

Comment: The original implementation in PHP outputs to binary, not hex (see the last parameter to the `hash()` function is `TRUE`). EDIT: I tested it just to be sure, and it definitely results in a different hash still.

Comment: Look at your NODE update it stringify's the binary output. In the PHP version you do not. I would use the `.digest('hex')` where possible in NODE, and do `bin2hex()` in PHP's side. That way you can keep the binary's out and work with the HEX values

Comment: I've provided an answer along with the output from my tests. PHP 7.4.16, and Node 14.16.0

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it without stringifying the data to `update()` in the Node.js implementation as well with the same results. Unfortunately, I can't change the PHP implementation--it's in the bowels of a web framework that I'm trying to move away from, but need to replicate the authentication mechanism while I transition away from it.

Comment: In the NodeJS code, `binary'` must be specified as the second parameter in the `update()` calls (default is UTF8, which corrupts the data, at least for the 2nd and subsequent `update()` calls). Then both codes return the same result on my machine.

Comment: That was it, @Topaco! It works now! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Please don't use a single hash iteration to hash passwords. Use many iterations through schemes such as Argon2, scrypt or PBKDF2. The first two are also memory-hard which means that they cannot be sped up by GPUs or ASICs. Password hashing is supposed to be slow See: [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on what my comment was I think the following might work.

NODE:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

const algorithm = 'sha512';
const salt = 'someSalt';
const password = 'somePassword';
let count = 32768;

let hash = crypto
        .createHash(algorithm)
        .update(String(salt) + String(password))
        .digest('hex');
// hash is the same as in the PHP implementation here
do {
  hash = crypto.createHash(algorithm).update(String(hash) + String(password)).digest('hex');
  // hash differs between the two implementations after the first pass here... why?
} while (--count);


console.log(hash);
```

PHP code:

```php
$algo = "sha512";
$salt = "someSalt";
$password = 'somePassword';
$count = 32768;

$hash = bin2hex(hash($algo, $salt . $password, TRUE));
// $hash is the same as in the corresponding line in the node.js implementation
do {
  $hash = bin2hex(hash($algo, $hash . $password, TRUE));
  // $hash differs from the node.js implementation after the first pass here... why?
} while (--$count);

var_dump($hash);
```

Confirmed my findings with the output from NODE:

```
node nodeTest.js
df8202221e5cbff38c16a33945efa8dcb44d0e7267cdf1514cefffb3df321f69ad1d9b01cfb6360391f1de4791e26a179fd165248b4b75699cb2d3395c971351
```

PHP output:

```
php test.php
string(128) "df8202221e5cbff38c16a33945efa8dcb44d0e7267cdf1514cefffb3df321f69ad1d9b01cfb6360391f1de4791e26a179fd165248b4b75699cb2d3395c971351"
```

Comment: I just posted this in response to another comment, but I'm unfortunately unable to modify the original PHP implementation since it's part of a web framework and that would break the existing authentication. I'm just attempting to replicate the authentication mechanism in Node.js so I can transition away from the PHP web framework.

Answer (score 0):

I had to pass `'binary'` to `update()` while hashing in the loop, since the data being provided is in binary.

```js
// The data being passed to update() here is string (update defaults to utf-8, I believe).
let hash = crypto
        .createHash(algorithm)
        .update(salt + password)
        .digest('binary');
do {
  // The data being passed to update() is binary.
  hash = crypto.createHash(algorithm).update(hash + password, 'binary').digest('binary');
} while (--count);
```

Credit: @Topaco for the finding the solution to my problem!